# Rials:When we use fields_for, how to initiate association_build if we are not sure how many association should be created?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

In such case:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :companies
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :companies
end

class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :users
end
```

This is nomal case, we're sure how many association we should create:

```
# user_controller 
def new
  @user = User.new
  2.times { @user.companies.build }
end
```

But what if we don't know how many association should be created?

Comment: hey, `2.times { @user.companies.build }` is to create association form fields at the initial step. For your requirement, you should add button to `create` and `delete` association form_fileds dynamically. please watch this http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised